# How to mock an object in a thread

Tags: java, mockito

I'm Mocking the java DateFormat class. The code I have to test is running in a thread, but the DateFormat object is not mocked.
The System.out.println() --->  value :20210409110350   and not  value :12345678  as I'm expecting,^.

> ```
> @Test
> public void test_1()  {
>
>     MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
>     myRunnable.run();
> }
>
>
> public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
>
>     public void run(){
>
>         DateFormat formatter = Mockito.mock(DateFormat.class);
>         Mockito.when(formatter.format(any(Date.class), any(StringBuffer.class),
>                 any(FieldPosition.class)))
>                 .thenReturn(new StringBuffer("12345678"));
>
>         MyClass  myClass = new MyClass();
>         myClass.myMethod();
>     }
> }
> ```

```
public class MyClass {

    public void myMethod() {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String timestamp = dateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println("value :" + timestamp);
    }
}
```

Comment: because `formatter` is mocked, not `dateFormat`

Comment: But that's what I want to obtain .... I'm mocking the formatter method and this is not woring :  Mockito.when(formatter.format(any(Date.class) .......

Comment: 1. You stub the wrong overload. 2. You don't pass mocked `DateFormat` to `MyClass`, and create a new `SimpleDateFormat` instead.

Comment: It seems that you have a fundamental misunderstanding: Mockito mocks an _object_, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock the date formatter that is used in MyClass, you should use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection):

```
public class MyClass {

    private final DateFormat dateFormat;

    public MyClass(DateFormat dateFormat) {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }

    public MyClass() {
        // Use default date format
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        Date date = new Date();
        String timestamp = dateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println("value :" + timestamp);
    }
}
```

and then use it in your test code like this:

```
public void run(){

    DateFormat formatter = Mockito.mock(DateFormat.class);
    Mockito.when(formatter.format(any(Date.class), any(StringBuffer.class),
            any(FieldPosition.class)))
            .thenReturn(new StringBuffer("12345678"));

    MyClass  myClass = new MyClass(formatter);
    myClass.myMethod();
}
```

Note that SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe, which means that you should create a new MyClass instance in every thread that you use it (or pass the formatter to the myMethod() method instead). Ideally, you should replace the use of the legacy DateFormat class with the new classes from the java.time package, which *are* thread-safe.

Comment: I cannot use dependency injection....upon that, MyClass is just an example class, the actual class to be tested  cannot be changed.

Comment: Then unfortunately you can't use a mock date formatter. The class to be tested has chosen to create an instance of a specific implementation of the formatter, and you are stuck with that. The format that the class produces is part of its functionality which can't be altered.